# Separate feature classes for individual entities vs one feature class with all entities as records. How to update for edits?

Tags: file-geodatabase, data-management

I have designed a directory on my computer with different multiple categorical geodatabases of boundary data. For example, using my **Cities_and_Towns** geodatabase, this GDB has 13 feature classes of polygon data for each city in my county. These feature classes all have one record.

Now, I have another geodatabase called **GIS_WEBMAP** that I use to host all of this boundary data to ArcGIS Online for a Web App. This geodatabase has categorical feature classes of boundary data. Using the same example, I have a **Cities_and_Towns** feature class. This feature class has 13 records that represent polygon boundary data for each city. And there's that.

I am the sole GIS Analyst in my agency and I am responsible for keeping our boundary data up-to-date based on annexations. I need to know of a way to update changes/edits to boundary data from the individual city feature classes that live in the **Cities_and_Towns** GBD to the specific record of interest for the **Cities_and_Towns** feature class from my **GIS_WEBMAP** GDB. Is there any tool that can allow me to somehow select the feature class that I edited to then update the specific record that represents the feature class that needs to be edited.

Comment: There is almost no demand for 13 discrete tables when you also have a single table with 13 rows. Create an index on the city-id and just use a definition query in layer files to reference the singletons by city-id. You could also use a topology in a feature dataset to enforce overlap restrictions. In this way, you use the software as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you could just use the [merge tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/merge.htm)
for this. You could automate it with ArcPy if you want.

A better way would be to just use [definition queries](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/definition-query.htm) to filter the individual layers and only use the webmap gdb.